# Why there are differences between the sunni and shia hadiths (in terms of books, ravi's etc)?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, shia-sunni, sahih-bukhari, ijma

I recently came to know that they are 6 main books of hadees of Ahle-Sunnat (Sahih Bukhari and Sahih Muslim and others) while Ahle-Tashee has 4 books along Nahjul-Balaga.

It made me to think,

- Why there are different books (and what seperates them)?
- How do scholars of both sides see books of each other?
- What were the principals used for collecting those ahadees?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please note that you are asking multiple questions in one single post (see [this discussion in our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)) each of them could need a book content to answer. To make it simple both sects are different in many aspects, especially from their political and partly theological interpretation so of course there's a lot of difference. As in each  side you may find people regarding the other as its opponent or even as a disbeliever.